# put focus to a textfield in popup

Tags: php, javascript, textbox, focus

I am using a popup box for adding a category.
script for that is

```
<script>
    function changeMenu(id)
    {
    if (id=='other')
    { //Getting the variable's value from a link 
    var loginBox = 'login-box';
    $('#login-box').fadeIn(300);
    var popMargTop = ($('#login-box').height() + 24) / 2; 
    var popMargLeft = ($('#login-box').width() + 24) / 2; 
    $('#login-box').css({ 
    'margin-top' : -popMargTop,
    'margin-left' : -popMargLeft
    });
    $('body').append('<div id="mask"></div>');
    return false;
    }
    }
</script>
```

html for popup is

```
<div id="login-box" class="login-popup">
<script>
    // When clicking on the button close or the mask layer the popup closed
    $('a.close, #mask').live('click', function() { 
    $('#mask , .login-popup').fadeOut(300 , function() {
    $('#mask').remove();  
    }); 
    return false;
    });
    </script>
    <a href="#" class="close"><img src="images/close_pop.png" class="btn_close" title="Close Window" alt="Close" /></a>
    <form method="post" class="signin" action="#" name="catform" id="catform">
    <table align="center" width="500" height="200" class="border2">
    <tbody><tr>
    <td bgcolor="#cccccc" align="center" class="txt_users">
    Add</td></tr>
    <tr bgcolor="#ffffff">
    <td align="center" colspan="2"><font color="#ff0000">
    </font>
    </td></tr>
    <tr bgcolor="#eeeee1">
    <td align="center"><span class="txt_sitedetails">
    Name</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="text" style="width: 300px;" value="" name="cat" id="cat" class="cat">
    <input type="hidden" value="1" name="cate">
    <input type="hidden" value="" name="mode">
    <input type="hidden" value="" name="id">
    <br><br><input type="submit" onclick="return val();" class="button" value="Submit" name="add">
    </td></tr>
    </tbody></table>
    </form>
</div>
```

I have to Put focus on name textfield in popup.I tried the below script

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
document.forms['catform'].elements['cat'].focus();
</script>
<script language="Javascript">
document.catform.cat.focus()
</script>
<script language="javascript">
$(function() {
    $('input.cat').focus();
});
</script>
```

But none of them works

Comment: would it work if you appended `autofocus` as a html5 atttribute to the input you want to be focused?

Answer (score 0):

Use id attribute to set focus on textfield.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#cat').focus();
});
```

Call this function in your popup page, when page load it will set focus on cat.